# import .less files into single .less without recompiling

Tags: css, less

I have, for example, 3 .less files and I want to import them to single one (base.less).
1file.less
2file.less
3file.less

I use @import "1file.less" to import them into base.less.

But when I look page code, the code from all 3 .less files compiled twice. How to make code compiles only from base.less.

Now it duplicates

```
body {
margin: 0;padding: 0;
background: #ffffff url(Images/background.png) repeat;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 100%;
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #ffffff url(Images/background.png) repeat;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 100%;
}
```

Thank you
P.S. sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `base.less` file should contain the following lines of code:

```
@import "1file.less";
@import "2file.less";
@import "3file.less";
```

You should only compile the `base.less` file.

You can use the command line `lessc` compiler, see: http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage. You should use the following command to compile:

```
>> lessc base.less > base.css
```

Alternatively you can use the client side compiler as describe at: http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser

Notice that you should only link the `base.less` file in your HTML. The `head` section of your HTML should contain the following lines of code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="base.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want files to compile you should start their names with an underscore

```
_1file.less
_2file.less
_3file.less
```

Not, you will have to import them with that 'new' name. Only files **without** the underscore get compiled.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/AssetsLess

Comment: This method doesn't work for me. My Base.less includes importing .less. Its made to create one big .less. These 3 files should be generated to Base.less but not to page by themselves.